# How does exists operator work? I don't know why the result happens

Tags: sql, select, oracle-sqldeveloper, exists

I thought that the following SQL statement returns lists salary less than 5000.
But I got salaries that are greater than or equal to 5000. I really don't know why. Did I miss something?

```
select salary 
from employees 
where exists (select 1 from employees e where salary < 5000);
```

Comment: You typically have a correlated subquery when you do EXISTS.

Comment: This query returns rows if there exists a user with salary < 5000 (no matter who it is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query inside the `exists` operator in your query returns at least one row, so the operator evaluates to `true`. The issue here is that it's not correlated to the outer query in any way, so it returns the same result for every row in the outer query (i.e., always `true`).

To get the result you want, you need to correlate between the queries by having a term from the outer query in the inner query's `where` clause:

```
SELECT salary
FROM   employees e1
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   employees e2 
               WHERE  e1.emp_id = e2.emp_id AND salary < 5000);
```

But, to be completely honest, you don't really need an `exists` operator here, and can just query the salary directly:

```sql
SELECT salary
FROM   employees
WHERE  salary < 5000
```